# PHP (WAMP) not sorting files the same way as Windows

Tags: php, sorting, wamp

Using WAMP, I'm trying to make PHP sort the same way as Windows using the following code:

```php
<?php
    $folder = opendir("folderx");
    $fileNameList = array();

    while(false !== ($fileName = readdir($folder))){
        array_push($fileNameList, $fileName);
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($fileNameList);
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

However, I'm getting weird results. This is how PHP is sorting:

```
Array
(
[0] => .
[1] => ..
[2] => New Text Document - Copy (2) - Copy - Copy.txt
[3] => New Text Document - Copy (2) - Copy.txt
[4] => New Text Document - Copy (2).txt
[5] => New Text Document - Copy (3) - Copy.txt
[6] => New Text Document - Copy (3).txt
[7] => New Text Document - Copy (4) - Copy.txt
[8] => New Text Document - Copy (4).txt
[9] => New Text Document - Copy - Copy (2) - Copy.txt
[10] => New Text Document - Copy - Copy (2).txt
[11] => New Text Document - Copy - Copy (3).txt
[12] => New Text Document - Copy - Copy - Copy (2).txt
[13] => New Text Document - Copy - Copy - Copy - Copy.txt
[14] => New Text Document - Copy - Copy - Copy.txt
[15] => New Text Document - Copy - Copy.txt
[16] => New Text Document - Copy.txt
[17] => New Text Document.txt
)
```

And this is how Windows is sorting:

[image]

Comment: This might help you understand the differences: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order.html though I don't know of a php implementation of this sorting.

Comment: I think the issue isn't different sorting, i think the PHP returns an unsorted array, then you should run a sorting method on it http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Comment: I've tried all the PHP sorting methods and none of them work.

Comment: I think the problem is in how PHP sorts symbols such as "(" and "-". 

PHP is giving preference to "(", whereas Windows is giving preference to "-".

Answer (score 2):

How about if you sort the array using natcasesort($fileNameList) like this:

```
<?php
$folder = opendir("folderx");
$fileNameList = array();

while(false !== ($fileName = readdir($folder))){
    array_push($fileNameList, $fileName);
}

function strip_non_cmp_characters($word) {
    return str_replace(array("(",")"," ","."),array("","","",""), $word);
}

function wincmp($a,$b) {
    return strnatcasecmp(strip_non_cmp_characters($a),
        strip_non_cmp_characters($b));
}

usort($fileNameList,"wincmp");

echo "<pre>";
print_r($fileNameList);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: I did't know about this.  Cool! +1

Comment: Sorry, I didn't look at your screenshots closely enough to see that the windows sorting algorithm is really weird. It must skip punctuation like ( ) and - and just sorts on the letters and numbers. Is copy even a special keyword too?

Comment: Probably too late, but here is my updated code that works in this one case at least: https://gist.github.com/tbelote/5969533

Answer (score 0):

You can use [scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) to order the files in alphabetical order. Opendir returns them as they are stored on the filesystem, not as they would show up in Windows.

Comment: Did you specify the sorting order as the second argument?

Comment: Then you'll probably better off writing your own algorithm if you really need it exactly as in Windows. http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php